# Flutter - I can not log in using Google account

Tags: android, firebase, dart, flutter, google-authentication

**When you click on the button, a window appears with a choice of Google account, I choose and instead of switching to a new page, I get an error. Error in the screenshot**

*My code:*

```
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

GoogleSignIn googleAuth = GoogleSignIn();
final FirebaseAuth _fAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final GoogleSignIn _gSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

 Future<FirebaseUser> _signInGoogle() async {
    GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await _gSignIn.signIn();
    GoogleSignInAuthentication authentication = await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

    var signInWithGoogle = signInWithGoogle;
    FirebaseUser user = await _fAuth.signInWithGoogle(
      idToken: authentication.idToken,
      accessToken: authentication.accessToken
    );
    return user;
  }


onPressed:() async {
  await _signInGoogle();                            
 Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/home_screen');
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncrjp.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5wH6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyMSp.png)

Comment: Well, or you can write your version of the code

Answer (score 1):

Did you add your SHA fingerprint?

Please check my answer for a similar question for how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54479992/679553